# Find the width and length of a rectangle given only the diagonal

Tags: geometry

Is it possible to find the width and length of a rectangle by just know the diagonal?  Like if the diagonal was 25, what would be the side lengths?

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT:  From the comments and solutions this is not possible.  Thanks for the explanations!

Comment: What are your thoughts on this?  Based on what you know about triangles, how many bits of information are required before you can start solving for unknowns?

Comment: No, for example with a diagonal $65$ you can have sides $39$ and $52$ or sides $25$ and $60$...

Comment: If you know the sides are whole numbers you may be able to solve this, depending on what the diagonal is.  There are some diagonals that still have multiple choices.

Comment: Apparently, nobody has thought of the angle between the diagonals :-)

Answer (score 0):

Say your diagonal was length $c$, and it’s width and height was $a$ and $b$ respectively, then these must satisfy

$$ a^2 + b^2 = c^2. $$

This has many solutions for $a$ and $b$ given the diagonal $c$.

Comment: Ok, I see how this is not solvable.  I need 2 pieces of info.

Answer (score 0):

No. By Pythagoras, if the width is $a$ and the length $b$, then,

$$a^2 + b^2 = 25^2$$

Any pair of numbers that satisfies that equation is a possible rectangle for that diagonal. For example, $a=15, b=20$, or $a=125/13, b=300/13$, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It is not enough to just know the length of the diagonal. But there are different additional hints that can make it possible.

- if the rectangle is a square the side $a=d/\sqrt2$
- if the ratio between the sides $r=a/b$ is known $b=\sqrt{\frac{d^2}{r^2+1}}$
- if the angle $\alpha$ between the diagonals is known $a=d\cdot sin(\frac{\alpha}{2})$

Those are some but not all possible hints that can help.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach. If you know the side of a triangle and the opposite angle, the possible locations of the vertex which isn't on the original side lie on an arc of a circle of known radius. With a right-angle the side you have is a diameter of the circle. The diagonal splits the rectangle into two triangles.

This is a lesser known consequence of the sine rule $$\frac a{\sin A}=2R$$ where $R$ is the radius of the circumcircle of the triangle.